# Can't display image with HeroCard in MS Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I created a bot using botframwork and created a HeroCard.
in web chat it work fine, but in MS Teams the image isn't presented.
Any idea what could be the problem?

```
        var heroCard = new HeroCard
        {
            Title = "title",
            Subtitle = "sub title",
            Text = " some text",
            Images = new List<CardImage>()
            {
                // some image for example
                new CardImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/June_odd-eyed-cat.jpg")
            },
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images must be at most 1024×1024 and 1 MB in PNG, JPEG, or GIF format; animated GIF is not officially supported.
Please have a look at [Inline card images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#inline-card-images)
 specifications.

I could see your [image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/June_odd-eyed-cat.jpg) dimensions are 2370x1927. Please try a different image and let us know if you face any issue.